# How to handle a DataServiceQuery that returns 0 matches

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I have created a simple WCF Data Service in Visual Studio 2013 in c#.

I then created a web application using asp.net and c#.

I have 2 textboxes and a button.

I put a code in the first text box.  I press the button.  the following code runs.  If the code i entered matches a record in the list exposed by the webservice, no problems.

However, if i enter a code that doesn't exist, I have no clues how to test for that.  Right now the only thing that works is a Try Catch, but I can't believe this is the proper of doing this.

```
 var proxy = new NorthwindEntities(new Uri("http://localhost:27214/NorthwindCustomers.svc"));

            var customers = proxy.Customers;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Code.Text))
            { return; }

            var customer = (from c in customers where c.CustomerID == Code.Text select c).Single();

            if (customer == null) //If there are no customers... it gives me an error.
            {
                Nom.Text = null;
            }
            else
            {
                Nom.Text = customer.CompanyName;
            }

            Code.Text = string.Empty;
```

Comment: What if you use SingleOrDefault() rather than Single()?

Comment: I tried that.. I get the same error....

An exception of type 'System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQueryException' occurred in Microsoft.Data.Services.Client.dll but was not handled in user code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this:-

You are getting error at this line:-

```
var customer = (from c in customers where c.CustomerID == Code.Text select c).Single();
```

because `(from c in customers where c.CustomerID == Code.Text select c)` **returns nothing** and **nothing.Single** is the cause of exception (**Sequence contains no matching elements**)

Replace it with this:-

```
var customer = customers.FirstOrDefault(c=> c.CustomerID == Code.Text);
```

**OR**

```
var customer = (from c in customers where c.CustomerID == Code.Text select c).SingleOrDefault();
```

It will fix the issue.

As a piece of advice please wrap this code inside a null check for the collection:-

```
if(customers != null)
{
var customer = customers.FirstOrDefault(c=> c.CustomerID == Code.Text);
.....
..... // Other code.
}
```